# При попытке отправить приложение в аппстор ошибка ERROR ITMS-90034 Missing or invalid signature

Tags: ios, xcode

При попытке отправить приложение на проверку в аппстор получаю вот такую ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю как решить, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: предположу, что подписано developer сертифкатом, а надо deployment. (отдельно создается в developer.apple.com)

Comment: пожалуйста не вставляйте скриншот с текстом ошибки, а пишите текст ошибки. Это поможет найти данный вопрос и ответ на него другим пользователям, столкнувшихся с подобной ошибкой.

Comment: distribution а не deployment*

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что 14 февраля закончился сертификат, которым Apple подписывает приложения перед отправкой в App Store.

Необходимо скачать и установить [новый сертификат](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer).

После установки надо запустить "Связку ключей" (Keychain Access), в меню "Вид" выбрать "Показать истекшие сертификаты", найти и удалить в связках "Вход" и "Система" истекший сертификат "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority".

Comment: что то в этом есть https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Comment: Я сделал все как вы написали, но все равно не помогло

Comment: Может перезагрузить xCode?

Comment: @EvgenySureev закрыл xcode и даже перезагрузил компьютер только что, зашел в xcode попытался отправить сборку, не получилось, та же ошибка

Comment: @EvgenySureev  сейчас даже создал новый архив и попытался проделать то же самое, все равно не получилось